# Integrate a two form on the sphere

Tags: calculus, surface-integrals, divergence-operator

$$
\int_S x\,dy\,dz+y\,dz\,dx+z\,dx\,dy,
$$ where $S=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^{3}: x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}.$

Please, I don't know how to proceed. I will be thankful if you give me any hint, at first I thought it was an application of the Stokes' Theorem, but the differentials confuse me D:
Thanks!

Comment: Please show us your work and where you got stuck so that we can help you.

Comment: I've made a mistake.... should say: I don't know how to proceed.....

Comment: The complete symmetry between $x$, $y$, and $z$ in both the integral and the definition of $S$ tells you the integrals of the three terms are equal. $\qquad$

Comment: It seems that this question is approaching closure. This is sad. Two of the closure votes given so far claim that it is not clear what the question asks. Wrong! The question is very clear, and it is not the OP's fault that two MSE users have absolutely no clue about surface integrals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quickest way to do this is by using the [Gauss-Ostrogradski theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem) (which is just another name for Stokes' theorem in $\Bbb R^3$ - you have correctly guessed that this would lead to the solution): if $V$ is a 3-dimensional region, then

$$\int \limits _{\partial V} P \ \Bbb dy \Bbb dz + Q \ \Bbb dz \Bbb dx + R \ \Bbb dx \Bbb dy = \int \limits _V \left( \frac {\partial P} {\partial x} + \frac {\partial Q} {\partial y} + \frac {\partial R} {\partial z} \right) \Bbb d x \Bbb d y \Bbb d z .$$

Concretely, if $B = \{ (x,y,z) \in \Bbb R^3 \mid x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \le 1\}$, then $S = \partial B$ and

$$\int \limits _S x \ \Bbb dy \Bbb dz + y \ \Bbb dz\Bbb dx + z \ \Bbb dx \Bbb dy = \int \limits _B \left( \frac {\partial x} {\partial x} + \frac {\partial y} {\partial y} + \frac {\partial z} {\partial z} \right) \Bbb d x \Bbb d y \Bbb d z = 3 \text{vol } (B) = 4 \pi .$$

Of course, you can also do it using the definition of surface integrals of the second type, but this would require you to use a parametrization, to compute the coefficients of the metric and the formula of the outer unit normal in this parametrization and finally to perform an integral, which is way too long and tedious.

Comment: Alex, I wasn't certain what the OP intended.  As written as "raw integrals," my interpretation was that these were the "first kind" integrals.  Then, as I was getting ready to sleep last night, I thought that maybe the OP meant these to be the two form, as you interpreted.  So, I believe that both interpretations are viable.

Comment: @BrunoMarceloGoicocheaVilela: Your question received two different interpretations (and also caused a series of comments that is now deleted) and also caused an answer that is now deleted. There is some ambiguity in your notation, due to the fact that you haven't used the "wedge" to denote 2-forms. More clearly, the integrand almost surely is supposed to be $x \ \Bbb d y \wedge \Bbb d z + y \ \Bbb d z \wedge \Bbb d x + z \ \Bbb d x \wedge \Bbb d y$. I suspect that this is why you claimed to be "confused by the differentials".

Comment: 1.-Maybe I'm wrong but I think that it can't be interpret as an ordinary surface integral since the surface where we are integrating is in $R^{3}$ and each term is a function in $R^{2}$  is that approach correct?

Comment: No, it's not. Had it been an ordinary surface integral, the volume form of $S$ should have been present  - which is clearly not the case here. For your reassuring, could you tell us where you took the problem from?

Comment: @BrunoMarceloGoicocheaVilela As Alex has described, there is a bit of "built-in" ambiguity in the question.  It is likely, in my opinion, that Alex's interpretation is the one intended.  However, it is easy to see by symmetry that the value of the integral would be zero if interpreted as an "ordinary" surface integral. -Mark

Comment: It's a final exam question. There's no much I can do sincerely thanks for the help...both of you. But I don't understand in which way the problem could be considering as an "ordinary" surface integral since in every term we could consider a function from $\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ but the surface where we are integrating is in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$

Comment: Consider the problem as a two-form integral is a good solution, but as @AlexM. said there's no wedge  :c

Comment: @BrunoMarceloGoicocheaVilela: There are professors who do not use the wedge sign, because they introduce second type surface integrals without discussing exterior differential forms (in order not to complicate things and scare students). The approach they take is to define $\int _{S_N} P \ \Bbb d y \Bbb d z + Q \ \Bbb d z \Bbb d x + R \ \Bbb d x \Bbb d y$ as $\int _S \langle (P, Q, R), N \rangle \ \Bbb d S$, where $N$ is a normal unit field to $S$, $S_N$ is $S$ with the orientation given by $N$ and the second integral is a first type surface integral. This is perfectly correct.

Comment: With that on mind there's no more doubts. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If we interpret the integral in the OP as an ordinary surface integral, then

$$\begin{align}
3 \int_S z\,dx\,dy &=3\int_{-1}^1\int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}\,dx\,dy+3\int_{-1}^1\int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\left(-\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}\right)\,dx\,dy\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

where we exploited the symmetry noting that $\int_S x\,dy\,dz=\int_S y\,dz\,dx=\int_S z\,dx\,dy$.

And we are done!

---

However, if we interpret the integral in the OP to be equivalent to the closed surface integral expressed as

$$\int_S x\,dy\wedge dz+y\,dz \wedge dx+z\,dx \wedge dy=\oint_S \vec r\cdot \hat n\,dS \tag 1$$

then we can apply the Divergence Theorem to the right-hand side of $(1)$ to reveal

$$\begin{align}
\oint_S \vec r\cdot \hat n\,dS &=\int_V \nabla \cdot \vec r\,dV\\\\
&=\int_V 3\,dV\\\\
&=3\frac{4\pi}{3}\\\\
&=4\pi
\end{align}$$

Alternatively, one can evaluate the surface integral directly as

$$\begin{align}
3\oint_S z\,n_z\,dS&=3\int_{-1}^1\int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}} \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}\,dx\,dy\\\\
&+3\int_{-1}^1\int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\left(- \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}\right)\,(-1)\,dx\,dy\\\\
&=6 \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-\rho^2}\,d\rho\,d\phi\\\\
&=4\pi
\end{align}$$

as expected!

Comment: Hmmm... this is a bit cheating: the previous (and previously deleted) version of this answer was *drastically* different (and wrong, too, since you had obtained the result to be $0$). After having significantly changed and undeleted it, it seems now that it had already been posted when I wrote mine, and that I have just copied it - clearly not true. I'm fine with you posting it, leave it here, I just want readers to know that I haven't copied it, as it may seem at a first view!

Comment: @AlexM. I decided to resurrect this answer with some edits to try and clarify the ongoing issue of interpretation.  I hope that you won't mind my doing so. -Mark

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\Vec}[1]{\mathbf{n}}$To complement the existing good answer: In classical notation, with $dS$ denoting the area element of the unit sphere and $\Vec{n}$ the outward unit normal field, your integral represents the flux through the unit sphere of the vector field
$$
F(x, y, z) = (x, y, z).
$$
This can be calculated directly by noting that on the unit sphere,
$$
F \cdot \Vec{n} = (x, y, z) \cdot (x, y, z) = x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2} = 1,
$$
so the flux of $F$ is
$$
\iint_{S} F \cdot \Vec{n}\, dS = \iint_{S} dS = \text{area of $S$} = 4\pi.
$$